# Tivoli to Autosys

Tags: autosys, tivoli

I am looking for a help in converting a IBM Tivoli script to Autosys since we have migrated from Tivoli to AUtosys.

Below is the script in Tivoli - 
SCHEDULE SX On RUNCYCLE YEARLY VALIDFROM 02/01/2015 "FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;"
UNTIL 0550 +5 DAYS
CARRYFORWARD
...
...

I need to convert this same script so that it can work in Autosys. Not sure, what Tivoli script means and what this Tivoli is doing and how I can convert it in run_calendar in AUtosys script
What about UNTIL and carryforward option ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a TWS Schedule (a set of jobs) that is set to run once a year starting 02/01/2015. It will start on that day at new plan generation and will run until 05:50 am after 5 days. CARRYFORWARD means that this schedule will not disappear at new plan generation that comes everyday.

This is not a script per se, this is a container of jobs. The Autosys calendar must look like a yearly job.